# How to have both: clean architecture and synchronization between domain models and persistence?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, persistence, clean-architecture, change-tracking

Imagine a `*.sln` with 4 projects:

1. `Project.Storage` (business logic models and interfaces to implement by infrastructure layer)
2. `Project` (main logic)
3. `Project.Storage.EntityFramework` (persistence layer which implements `Project.Storage`)

In `Project.Storage` we have defined model as below:

```
public class Grant
{
    public string GrantId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuthorizationDetail> AuthorizationDetails { get; set; } = new List<AuthorizationDetail>();
    public ICollection<string> Claims { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>();
    public DateTime GrantedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And simple interface for it:

```
public interface IGrantStore
{
    Task UpdateAsync(string grantId, Action<Grant> update, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

The interface is implemented as below in `Project.Storage.EntityFramework`:

```
public class GrantStore : IGrantStore
{
    private readonly GrantsDbContext _dbContext;

    public GrantStore(GrantsDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(string grantId, Action<Grant> update, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var entity = await _dbContext.Grants.FindAsync(new string[] { grantId }, cancellationToken);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            update(entity);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is with synchronization between logic and persistence. If we want to update the as domain model and in my database, then I have to modify properties of instance of domain model, and then call `UpdateAsync` from store to update it in database. I do the same thing two times.

```
public async Task SomeMethod(Grant grant, CancellationToken cancellactionToken = default)
{
    var newAuthorizationDetails = //something
    var newClaims = //something

    grant.AuthorizationDetails = newAuthorizationDetails;
    grant.Claims = newClaims;

    await _grantStore.UpdateAsync(grant.GrantId, update =>
    {
        grant.AuthorizationDetails = newAuthorizationDetails;
        grant.Claims = newClaims;
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

How to avoid it while I use Clean Architecture? I don't think depending on Change Tracking provided by EF is good, because what if someone uses eg. Dapper without Change Tracking (or how EF could know when to use tracking or not)?

In simple words, how to update the domain model and make some magic that allow persistence layer to detect change and do appropriate query to database?

Comment: Maybe just use `ExecuteUpdateAsync` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.executeupdateasync?view=efcore-7.0 which allows you to directly execute a `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` on the database without retrieving the model object.

Comment: But I assume that I don't know anything about persistence layer. I don't know whether this layer uses relational database.

Comment: You would implement a new class that implements IGrantStore for dapper. I dont understand the problem. Maybe you could Show how you update the model in the Domain layer.

Comment: I added example code where the problem occurs. I first must update instance that flows through application in current context, and then update database.

Comment: Ah ok. Your Igrand update method could return the updated entity. AsNotracking() could prevent the Tracking for EF core.

Comment: Or as @Charlieface already mentioned. You can execute directly without the tracking, see the mentioned link.

Comment: I gave too simple example. Imagine that I have some DI service that updates 2 or more instances using 2 or more stores (like `IGrantStore`). I don't want to return updated object for every instance, but also I don't want to doing update twice for one instance :/

Comment: If you want to update only once. there is no option but the db layer. Think about primary keys or changedates written by the db.

Comment: What about sending updated entity to `UpdateAsync` in Store along with something like `Expression<Func<Grant, object>>[] properties` to indicate which properties needs to be updated (so e.g. set EntityState to Modified for indicated properties)? Do you see any possible errors with that?

Comment: I dont see a benefit there. The db layer already knows about the changes since it has the original DB entity.